# Understanding Genset KVAR

Tags: generator

I have a 150 KVA genset on a remote work site in Indonesia.  It is new and has a microcontroller that gives all kinds of information we have never had at our fingertips before.

I have been reading about KVAR, how it relates to active and reactive power, and the usual things that you would find in a google search. But it is all related to much bigger installations and I would like to know how it practically relates to our small genset.

Just now we are not processing a harvest so not using all our big load equipment, but as we are doing an oil change on our smaller unit we have the 150  kva unit online for a bit.  because of this and the new information from the display first time I have some information on our base load for the camp.  I noted the fallowing:

```
Load 50 KVA
kVar 21
L1 pfLg 0.91
L1 pfLg 0.90
L1 pfLg 0.80
```

I believe pfLg is Power factor lagging.

I generally understand lag and lead with respect to phase angle, and load types. But what is the practical effect on genset life, efficiency and most importantly fuel consumption?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: The power factor and kVAR's don't matter, because you're using a generator, not the national power grid.

Detailed: Your generator can supply a rated output of kVA, at any power factor. The rating reflects the amount of electrical current the armature windings in your generator can sustain. without burning the insulation.

*If* you were paying for electricity from a power utility company, they would charge you based on the amount of electrical *current* you took from them, because current makes their power lines hot also, that heat costs them money, and there is a limit to how much current the power lines can carry, just like there is in your generator. So if you're using the current, someone else can't, therefore, they  charge you for it.

VAR's (kVAR's) is the electrical power which (most commonly) magnetizes the field in an electric motor (energy *storage*), and is returned to the supply each half cycle. It is not consumed by the motor, just borrowed. So in the case of your generator, motors are borrowing and returning power twice every cycle. The diesel engine driving your generator only knows about the kW's, so you won't save money or fuel by correcting the power factor with an auto-switching capacitor bank (to handle the borrow/return) in this case, as you *would* if drawing power from the national grid.

Comment: More current means more heat and more fuel consumption (power dissipation from extra current). While saving fuel may be not worth it, the closer pf to 1 the less is the danger of overheating the generator.  If you have pf less than rated then you will not be able to output rated active power.